# docz build failed - can't resolve 'dom-helpers/util/requestAnimationFrame' in 'filepath'

Tags: reactjs, build

I'm trying to run docz (https://www.docz.site/).
I have following script on package.json

```
"docz:dev": "docz dev",
"docz:build": "docz build",
```

And when I run docz or build, I get an error that

```
Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/util/requestAnimationFrame'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your package.json

`"resolutions": { "react-transition-group": "4.0.0" }`

[Source](https://github.com/doczjs/docz/issues/1102)

Comment: Hello, I've added now and tried to run build again, and having a same error. Is there anything I have to do after adding that resolutions line? Thanks.